# Question based on finding the last digit of a number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The digits of the number N are added to get another number. Then the digits of the number obtained are added to get yet another number. The process is repeated till a single digit number is obtained. What is that single digit number?
I have no clue how to do this one. Please try to help me out. I will be really grateful

Comment: Why it is being downvoted? :(

Comment: In elementary school, did you ever learn a technique to check your results called "casting out nines"?  If you didn't look it up.  It applies here.

Comment: No, I don't know. @DougM Can you please explain?

Comment: When you add the 10's digit to the ones digit you are subtracting by some multiple of 10 and adding by some multiple of 1.  Which basically means you are subtracting by a multiple of $9.$

Comment: Okay, I didn't understand :'( @DougM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is that the remainder after division by 9 does not change if you replace a number by the sum of its digits. This follows easily from the fact that each power of 10 leaves remainder 1 after division by 9. Thus, the final one-digit number can be determined from the remainder of the original number divided by 9.

Comment: I am finding it very hard to understand this technique @ReinerMartin

Comment: I understood by taking an example @ReinerMartin You made it look so easy. Thankyou so much